# Changing td value with select and not propagating event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a jsfiddle that replace a td value with a select with 2 values: http://jsfiddle.net/B47km/

When i click the td, the select appears, but when i'm going to see the option elements the click event of the td throws and i can't show the options. How can i solve this?

The HTML:

```
<table>
    <td class="test">1</td>
</table>
```

The js code:

```
$(function () {
    $(".test").click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        var currentEle = $(this);
        var value = $(this).html();
        select = '<select class="select-dorsal form-control" type="text">'
        +'<option name="1" value="1">1</option>'
        +'<option name="2" value="2">2</option>'
        +'</select>';
        $(currentEle).html(select);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery [**`one()`**](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method , which will only listen the event once

```
$(function () {
    $(".test").one('click',function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        var currentEle = $(this);
        var value = $(this).html();
        select = '<select class="select-dorsal form-control" type="text">'
        +'<option name="1" value="1">1</option>'
        +'<option name="2" value="2">2</option>'
        +'</select>';
        currentEle.html(select);
    });
});
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/B47km/8/)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it for you http://jsfiddle.net/B47km/3/ This will replace the cell content just once not every time you click on it.

```
$(function () {
    $(".test").click(function (e) {
        var currentEle = $(this);
        var value = $(this).html();

        if ($(this).find('select').length === 0)
        {
            select = '<select class="select-dorsal form-control" type="text">'
            +'<option name="1" value="1">1</option>'
            +'<option name="2" value="2">2</option>'
            +'</select>';
            $(currentEle).html(select);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a better way (I am a bit rusty on JQuery) but

```
    if (!$(e.target).hasClass('test')) {
        return
    }
```

To see if the click event came from the `td` or the `select` seems to fix the plnkr.

Answer (score 0):

Although you've not said explicitly, I'm guessing you're trying to implement a click to change, select a new value and then put that back in (removing the select).  In which case:

```
$(function () {
    $('.test').click(function (e) {
        var td = $(this);

        var select = $(document.createElement('select')).attr('name', 'select_name').attr('class', 'select-dorsal form-control'),
            curVal = parseInt(td.get('text'));
        for(var i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
            select.append('<option value="' + i + '"' + (curVal == i ? ' selected="selected"' : '') + '>' + i + '</option>');
        }            

        td.html(select);
        select.on('click', function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); });

        select.on('change', function(e) {
            var newVal = parseInt(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);
            td.html(newVal);
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/B47km/10/